# A complicated logstash pattern in Grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have following 3 lines in a log that need to be grok'd for ElasticSearch through logstash.

```
2020-01-27 13:30:43,536 INFO  com.test.bestmatch.streamer.function.BestMatchProcessor  - Best match for ID: COi0620200110450BAD5CB723457A9B4747F1727 Total Batch Processing time: 3942
2020-01-27 13:30:43,581 INFO  HTTPConnection                                              - COi0620200110450BAD5CB723457A9B4747F1727 | People: 51 | Addresses: 5935 | HTTP Query Time: 24
2020-01-27 13:30:43,698 INFO  bestRoute                                                    - COi0620200110450BAD5CB723457A9B4747F1727 | Touch Points: 117 | Best Match Time 3943
```

I tried various grok patterns but couldn't get to any concrete one.

### Edited as per request

I need the following in ES in the context of the specific log entry

1st line

```
ID: COi0620200110450BAD5CB723457A9B4747F1727 
Total Batch Processing time: 3942
```

2nd Line

```
ID: COi0620200110450BAD5CB723457A9B4747F1727 
People: 51 
Addresses: 5935 
HTTP Query Time: 24
```

3rd Line

```
Touch Points 117 
Best Match Time: 3943.
```

The output is from a Flink log. If there are flink patterns out there then please let me know.

Comment: What fields do you need? I mean, this can be parsed in very different ways with a lot of different outputs (fields). Coud you provide an example of the end result you want so we can provide you the grok filters to achieve that?

Comment: I added an edit to my original post

Comment: Ok. For the first line, can you check if this works as you need? (I added a couple more of fields just 'cause). If this works, I could make the other two. Also, I can exaplain them if you want/need me to. ^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.*ID: (?<ID>[\w\d]*).*time: (?<total_time>[\d]*)$

Answer (score 1):

1st line:

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.*ID: (?<ID>[\w\d]*).*time: (?<total_time>[\d]*)$
```

2nd line:

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.* - (?<ID>[\w]*).*People: (?<people>[\w]*).*Addresses: (?<addresses>[\d]*).*HTTP Query Time: (?<query_time>[\d]*)$
```

3rd line:

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.* - (?<ID>[\w]*).*Touch Points: (?<touch_points>[\d]*).*Best Match Time (?<best_match_time>[\d]*)$
```

There are many ways to parse this, this is only one approach. I would reccomend to adjust the field names I used to the new ECS. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I wanted to stay away from regex since I will be ingesting a lot of logs. I don't know what kind of performance hit it would be...But it is a solution and it seems that's the only thing that will work..How do I go about applying these since these lines will be repeated over and over again.?

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I go about applying these..." Are you worried about performance issues? Because if you are, that would be subject of another question. Or are you asking about how to implement these filters in a logstash(or elasticsearch ingest pipeline) filter? (which would be another question too) :)

Comment: I know hot to implement them in the logstash filter. What I am wondering is how do I make a decision on which grok pattern to apply? These lines could come in any order in the log file. For a standard HTTP output, the grok pattern runs through each line. I don't have the liberty here :). I agree performance is another issue

Comment: I was trying the first line with the GROK pattern you provided in the GROK debugger. Didn't work!
Line: 
2020-01-27 13:30:43,536 INFO  com.test.bestmatch.streamer.function.BestMatchProcessor  - Best match for ID: COi0620200110450BAD5CB723457A9B4747F1727 Total Batch Processing time: 3942
Pattern: 
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}.*ID: (?<ID>[\w\d]*).*time: (?<total_time>[\d]*)$

Comment: It did work. Something was wrong with Chrome and the grok debugger. I used some other browser.

Comment: Nice to hear :)